# Multiple strings to search within a string in python

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing

I have to search some words within a string in one statement. Can anyone help me do that in python?

For e.g. - words to be search are : `abc`, `abd`, `adb`, `mm`, `nn`. 
String to be searched:

```
aaassgshshhshsjskslskhalhslkhslkhsshalkjlkjmmmmabcabd
```

I want something like this:

```
search(abc, abd, adb, mm, nn, "aaassgshshhshsjskslskhalhslkhslkhsshalkjlkjmmmmabcabd")
```

and output should be yes if any of the word matches otherwise no.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need regex here, use [any()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any):

```
>>> s = "aaassgshshhshsjskslskhalhslkhslkhsshalkjlkjmmmmabcabd"
>>> l = ['abc', 'abd', 'adb', 'mm', 'nn']
>>> any(i in s for i in l)
True
```

Just, FYI, the regex aproach:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "aaassgshshhshsjskslskhalhslkhslkhsshalkjlkjmmmmabcabd"
>>> pattern = "abc|abd|adb|mn|nn"
>>> re.search(pattern, s)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb7088138>
```

Comment: Note that the Regex approach will only do one pass through the string, so is probably better.